# Android sqlite db query can't get correct data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a question.

Have a table like this:

```
(table name: times)
+-------+-----------+---------+
| block | startTime | endTime |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 | 08:00     | 10:00   |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

when I use rawquery like this:

```
String ctime = "'09:45'";
cursor = sdb.rawQuery(String.format("select block from times where startTime < time(%s) and endTime> time(%s)", ctime,ctime), null);
```

I Can get the correct data "1".

But when I use query like this:

```
cursor = sdb.query("times", new String[]{"block"}, "startTime <= time(?) and EndTime >= time(?)", new String[]{ctime,ctime}, null, null, null);
```

I can't get the correct data.
The Cursor count is 0.

Why??

Comment: Try adding single quotes around `%s`.

Comment: why are you storing time as HH:MM  and not as a number of seconds/minutes?

Comment: `HH:MM` is a **valid** time string in SQLite - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid time string must not contain quotes.

The quotes in your `ctime` variable are correct when you are constructing the SQL statement by hand, but they are used to delimit the SQL string and are not part of the value of the SQL string.

When you are using parameters, you do not need to put quotes around strings (unless you actually want them to be part of the string's value).